# Binding only works using ElementName, why?

Tags: wpf, binding

Here is some code snippets of my scenario. On the .xaml side I have an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StatList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource statBox}"></ItemsControl>
```

The StatList is simply a List of objects.

The DataTemplate contains this TextBlock

```
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DataTextBlock" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Foreground="White" FontSize="11">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                            <iBehaviors:InvokeMethodTrigger Method="UpdateBinding"
                                    Target="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    Parameter="{Binding ., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
```

This works the first time I set my StatList on my ViewModel, the TextBlock itself is passed as the Parameter to the InvokeMethodTrigger. However, if I change the StatList on my viewmodel, the next time the Loaded event occurs, the Parameter is null when the InvokeMethodTrigger is triggered.

Oddly enough, when I change the Parameter binding to:

```
Parameter="{Binding ElementName=DataTextBlock}"
```

it works the second time when I change my StatList, with the TextBlock being passed as the parameter. I for my life can't figure out why! Any explanations?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this in code behind:

```
    SlatList slat = new SlatList();
    ItemControl.ItemSource = slat;
    ItemControl.DataContext = slat;
```

make sure to specify a name for the itemcontrol and replace "ItemControl" with the name.

In XAML:

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StatList}" DataContext="{Binding SlatList} ItemTemplate="{StaticResource statBox}"> </ItemsControl>
```